# Rotation of raster image in atlas using QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, atlas, resolution, rotate

I am currently dealing with a mind-numbing problem. I am creating an atlas that has photos as a part of it. The images are loaded through an attribute with relative link. Everything loads just fine but QGIS cannot recognise what orientation the photo should have (in metadata it is determined by height and width resolutions that are different for portrait formats and landscape portraits). The atlas puts them all with the longest side down. This mean that some photos are 90° off.

Is there a way to rotate some of the images that are wrong automatically?

E.g. can I somehow extract resolution of loaded raster image in the atlas in QGIS and based on the resolution of either height or width rotate in 90° back?

So far I could not find any command, value or variable in the field calculator that extracts this. If there is any other way to determine the wrong orientation that would be of equal help.

To clarify about the problem. I have images stored in the same directory as the QGIS file. One layer that is the basis for Atlas has relative path to the correct photos as an attribute. In the layout for atlas I have Image object that has the attribute of the layer as a path. This means that for each atlas page there is a different picture. But if some pictures have been photoed as a portrait, the QGIS doesnt know it and lays them as panorama. But the pictures retain the info about the orientation.

Comment: Can you provide an image, and describe a bit more detailled, how you add the images to the layout?

Comment: I think you might have to write some python code to pull out the EXIF metadata from the image, if that's where the orientation is stored. I couldn't find a plugin that matches "EXIF" in the search box so looks like its not been done yet...

Comment: I am not at the PC with the files right now, I will provide picture later. As for the detailed description. I have images stored in the same directory as the QGIS file. One layer that is the basis for Atlas has relative path to the correct photos as an attribute. In the layout for atlas I have Image object that has the attribute of the layer as a path. This means that for each atlas page there is a different picture. But if some pictures have been photoed as a portrait, the QGIS doesnt know it and lays them as panorama. But the pictures retain the info about the orientation. Is it clearer?

Comment: Please [Edit the Question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those would help to need to sift through the comments for critical information.